# Can't resolve SQLiteException: near "SELECT": syntax error (code 1)

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to get data from database. When I click on item in listview it should get me all data for clicked item. but I'm getting this error and cannot resolve it.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.matija.ams/com.example.matija.ams.DisplayLogs}:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "SELECT": syntax error
>   (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Logs WHERE id IN SELECT id
>   FROM logs_recepits WHERE id =?
>                                                                          
> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "SELECT":
>   syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Logs WHERE id
>   IN SELECT id FROM logs_recepits WHERE id =?

```
public ArrayList<Logs> getAllLogs(long id) {
        ArrayList<Logs> logList = new ArrayList<Logs>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOGS + " WHERE " + KEY_ID  + " IN " + ( "SELECT " + KEY_ID + " FROM " + TABLE_LOGS_BELONGS_TO_RECEPIT + " WHERE " + RECEPIT_ID + " =?");

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});

        //going throug all rows and adding it to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Logs log = new Logs();
                log.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
                log.setCreatedAt(cursor.getString(1));
                log.setPlate_number(cursor.getString(2));
                log.setSort_id(cursor.getString(3));
                log.setGrade(cursor.getString(4));
                log.setDiameter(cursor.getString(5));
                log.setLength(cursor.getString(6));
                logList.add(log);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return logList;
    }
```

**Question: How should I resolve this error?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like misplaced brackets

Try this

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOGS + " WHERE " + KEY_ID  + " IN " + "(SELECT " + KEY_ID + " FROM " + TABLE_LOGS_BELONGS_TO_RECEPIT + " WHERE " + RECEPIT_ID + " =?)";
```

Comment: Perfect. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:
Brackets Should be inside in the `""`

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOGS + " WHERE " + KEY_ID  + " IN " +  "(SELECT " + KEY_ID + " FROM " + TABLE_LOGS_BELONGS_TO_RECEPIT + " WHERE " + RECEPIT_ID + " =?)";
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. @Rohit5k2 has answered first so I'll accept his answer but I'll upvote yours.

Comment: NP happy to help you. Happy Coding :)